# How to solve the integral $\int (\frac{2}{x^3}+\frac{1}{x})\cdot \sin x\, \operatorname{d}x$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I've tried a couple of substitutions, even a desperate one by parts, but nothing has worked for me.

Comment: Distribute the product.  The term $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ can be dealt with via a single integration by parts step.  The other term can also be handled via integration by parts, but you are going to have to do it a couple of times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that

\begin{align}
\int \frac{1}{x}\sin x\mathop{dx}&=   -\frac{1}{x}\cos x- \int \frac{1}{x^2}\cos x\mathop{dx}\\
&=-\frac{1}{x}\cos x- \left( \frac{1}{x^2}\sin x +\int \frac{2}{x^3}\sin x\mathop{dx}\right)\\
&=-\frac{1}{x}\cos x- \frac{1}{x^2}\sin x -\int \frac{2}{x^3}\sin x\mathop{dx}
\end{align}
Therefore,

$$\int \left(\frac{2}{x^3}+\frac{1}{x}\right)\sin x\mathop{dx} =-\frac{1}{x}\cos x- \frac{1}{x^2}\sin x +C $$

Comment: Edited: there were some residual $dx$ left in the text out of integrals. Also you can use `\mathop{dx}` to get correct spacing.

Comment: Ahh I hate it when I need to figure out the answer before even starting to compute. It's simple only when I notice something like that. Is there another method, like computing the whole at once?

Comment: @zwim Thanks for the edit, and the tip, which, admittingly, I was unaware of .

Comment: @TomekCejko I think all of the different ways would essentially boil down to this method, as the integral $\int \frac{1}{x} \sin x \mathop{\text{d}x}$ cannot be solved using elementary functions. This technique, is hard to see when you are not used to it. However, there times when this type of symmetry argument is used for instance when computing $\int e^{ax} \sin bx$. You integrate by parts twice and then you end up with the same function.